# Java timertask wont stop when .cancel() is called

Tags: java, button, timer, timertask, pause

I have the following timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        intCounter.incrementCount();
        System.out.println(intCounter.counterNum);
    };
};
```

It runs when the start button is pressed and should stop when the pause button is pressed however it will not stop. Here is the code for my pause button, the text "pressed pause" prints however the timer continues to count.

```
        if (e.getSource() == pauseButton) {
        System.out.println("pressed pause");
        task.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
```

EDIT:
I have tried modifying my code with an answer posted for a similar question but the result did not change. I changed my TimerTask to look like this:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    private volatile Thread thread;

    public void run() {
        thread = Thread.currentThread();
        intCounter.incrementCount();
        System.out.println(intCounter.counterNum);
    }

    public boolean cancel() {
        Thread thread = this.thread;
        if (thread != null) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }
        return super.cancel();
    }
};
```

Comment: You're working with a gui, so you should use ```javax.swing.Timer```

Comment: @g00se what is the difference and will it solve this problem or is it a good practice kind of thing?

Comment: It's really because code that's running in an arbitrary user-created thread won't synchronize naturally well with the main thread of your gui (its event dispatch thread)

Comment: Okay I can change that but do you have any idea of how to fix the cancel method?

Comment: ```javax.swing.Timer``` has ```javax.swing.Timer.stop()```

Comment: Thank you im attempting to change it now but I'm struggling a bit to make the timer work, would you be able to show me what I should be changing from my original?

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. All you need is a JFrame with two buttons, "Start" and "Stop". When the "Start" button is clicked you start the Timer and have it fire every second. When the Timer fires, display something simple like the Date. Then when you click the Stop button you stop the timer. Get this basic functionality working and then fix your real problem. The point of creating the MRE is to have a simple, complete example you can post if you don't solve the problem while creating the MRE.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your task should look like:

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    private boolean cancelled = false;

    public void run() {
        int x = 1000; // so many chunks to work on
        while (x > 0 && !cancelled) {
            // perform one chunk of work
            x--;
        }
    }

    public boolean cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help however this has not resolved the issue and it still continues to count after being cancelled.